# How to Open a password-protected MDB file in VB NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am creating an app using VB .NET.

I would like to create a button function to import a MDB file into the application to extract a specific table stored in MDB.

How do I check if MDB file is password-protected?

How do I open MDB file in VB.NET? I have a file path for that MDB.

Once I manage to open MDB file, how do I extract a table from that MDB file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got ACE OLEDB, your connection string would look like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

If you're using Jet 4.0, it would look like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

As for checking to see if it's password protected, you could trap for an error if you don't supply a password, because then you'll know it needs one.